# Why do I get an assertion failure?

Tags: c, fgets, assertion

This code fails when I try to debug it using VC2010:

```
char frd[32]="word-list.txt";

FILE *rd=fopen(frd,"r");
if(rd==NULL)
{
std::cout<<"Coudn't open file\t"<<frd;
exit(1);
}
char readLine[100]; 
while(fgets(readLine, 100, rd) != NULL)
{     
    readLine[strlen(readLine) - 1] = '\0'; 
    char *token = NULL; 
    token = strtok(readLine, " ,"); 
    insert(readLine);
}
```

Debugging results in

> --------------------------- Microsoft Visual C++ Debug Library-----------
>
> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program: ...\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\bfa\Debug\bfa.exe
>   File: f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\fgets.c Line: 57
>
> Expression: ( str != NULL )
>
> For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure,
>   see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
>
> (Press Retry to debug the application)
>
> ### --------------------------- Abort   Retry   Ignore

The errno I get is 2;

Comment: My guess is that the file is failing to open, and you're still passing it to fgets.  Your if(rd==NULL) doesn't stop execution of the fgets if it's null, it just prints out a message and continues with execution.

Comment: @Corbin: that should be an answer, not a comment.  `str` is probably short for _stream_.

Comment: @Corbin: thanks! can you tell why the file is failing to open?

Comment: What I had in mind for my comment was originally much shorter than that.  Have put it as an answer though :).  And John, you'll need to either do some error checking (errno) for that.  Also, check that file permissions are right, and that the file does actually exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that the file is failing to open, and you're still passing it to fgets.  Your if(rd==NULL) doesn't stop execution of the fgets if it's null, it just prints out a message and continues with execution.

Some very basic errorr handling:

```
const char* frd = "word-list.txt";

FILE *rd=fopen(frd,"r");
if(rd==NULL) {
    std::cout<<"Coudn't open file"<<endl;
    return 1;
}

char readLine[100]; 
while(fgets(readLine, 100, rd) != NULL)
{     
    readLine[strlen(readLine) - 1] = '\0'; 
    char *token = NULL; 
    token = strtok(readLine, " ,"); 
    insert(readLine);
}
```

Comment: can you tell why the file is failing to open?

Comment: errno is 2. but I don't know what it is

Comment: errno = 2 usually means "file not found." Use strerror to get the proper error message.

Comment: errno 2 is "no such file or directory". Make sure you run your program in a directory where that file exists, or specify a full path in your code.

Comment: @John, you can look in errno.h (where it will be depends on your OS/compiler).  There might be a list online, but as far as I know, the error numbers are not standardized save a few and thus each compiler might have its own set.

Comment: i specified the full path of the file in the code and now the error is changed to errno 22 "invalid argument"

Comment: To get the string value of an error code (since you are using visual studio) use Tools->Error Lookup.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and John is right what happened was my Anti Virus corrupte some files of the ap I replaced them and problem solved.