# fgets gives assetion, trying to redistribute vs2010 MFC application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, mfc, fgets

I have a simple application which reads a few text files does some calculations and writes a few text files.  Works perfect on my development machine (Server2008R2 VC++ 2010).  I can't get it to run on a Win7 machine even thought I have installed/run the vs2010 redistribute x86.

The first error I got was missing mfc100ud.dll (yes, I'm using debug, if I try the release it just crashes, as debug tells you what's wrong).  I put mfc100ud.dll in the application's directory, now fgets asserts as shown below.  str is not null and the file did open successfully.

What have I missed?

My goal here is to just run the MFC app on the Win7 machine without have to install vs2010.

Another consideration, the only reason I am using MFC is for the COleTimeDate functionality.  I've looked for alternatives but haven' found anything workable or as simple to use.

Thanks.

[Assertion Error](http://jimster.ca/files/code/assertion.jpg)

Comment: Shipping the *debug* version of your MFC application..? Ugh.If this crashes on a release-build install on a machine, you can still debug it (maybe not interactively, but at least crash analysis). Make sure your release build has a full pdb set, and use WinDbg on the target machine. properly setup with the symbol path and the source file package, you can probably get what you need (and fair warning, "robust" is a gross understatement when describing the WinDbg interface).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634158/why-do-i-get-an-assertion-failure

Answer (score 0):

This error occures if the file stream pointer (provided by fopen) is NULL.
Is it possible that you don't have any error checking after you used fopen?

Basically use "static linking" to the MFC and CRT. Than there is no Need to install and copy any runtime files.

Answer (score 0):

Redistributable assemblies are only available for release builds. If you really want to distribute a debug build, you have two options:

- link your app statically, so you don't need any shared DLL (such as mfc100ud.dll)
- distribute together with your app (in your app folder) all the dependent DLLs. you can check the dependencies with depends.exe